# Making a table with html and css, but nothing is aligned

Tags: html, css

I am currently making a table in the bottom part of my website. There are 3 columns, and I am trying to get them to be aligned. I have text-align in my CSS as well. However, the middle column is off to the right, and the box from the table is as well. I don't really have any idea what is causing this and how I can fix it/a better way to go about doing this. Some help would be greatly appreciated!

```css
.counties {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  background: #7d7d7d;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table class="counties" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Counties</th>
    <th>Cases</th>
    <th>Deaths</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>example</td>
    <td>example</td>
    <td>example</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>example</td>
    <td>example</td>
    <td>example</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code presented here. Please [edit] your question with code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: maybe a parent or higher tag could cause the wrong alignment as you can see from your example the table columns are aligned center.

Comment: Do you want them to be left-aligned instead of centered?

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now. The center column is not centered to the table because tables adjust the width of columns to fit their content. The word "countries" is longer than "cases" or "deaths", so that column is wider, pushing the center column to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The center column is not centered to the table because tables adjust the width of columns to fit their content. The word "countries" is longer than "cases" or "deaths", so that column is wider, pushing the center column to the right.

This happens when the `table-layout` CSS property is set to `auto`, which it is by default. To make the columns equal width, set `table-layout` to `fixed`.

In the example below, the first table has `table-layout: auto` and the second has `table-layout: fixed`. You can see that in the second option, the center column is in the true middle of the table, as I think you desire.

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table {
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.table-1 {
  table-layout: auto;
}
.table-2 {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-1" style="width:300px">
  <tr>
    <th>Counties</th>
    <th>Cases</th>
    <th>Deaths</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>example</td>
    <td>example</td>
    <td>example</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>example</td>
    <td>example</td>
    <td>example</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="table-2" style="width:300px">
  <tr>
    <th>Counties</th>
    <th>Cases</th>
    <th>Deaths</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>example</td>
    <td>example</td>
    <td>example</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>example</td>
    <td>example</td>
    <td>example</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```